# Show specific records to Users based on their settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have set up devise and added a way for users to save settings or preferences. For simplicity lets say that the setting is set as a boolean in the users table.

A simple version of what I want is for a user to have a size preference.

If a user is logged in and they visit the home page (products#index) I would like them to only see products that match the setting they have selected. (obviously the product has a size field)

I also have search enabled for the products and would like to keep that functionality intact for the user using their settings

```
def index
  @products = Product.text_search(params[:query]).page(params[:page]).per_page(50)
  #@products = Product.all
  respond_with(@products)
end
```

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: @products = Product.where(size: current_user.size)  ... something like that?

Comment: This worked great but I've edited my question to add more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def index
 @products = Product.where(size: current_user.size).text_search(params[:query]).page(params[:page]).per_page(50)
 #@products = Product.all
 respond_with(@products)
end
```

Should solve your issue

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm.